# why same regex expression gives two different results?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

Hi I have two typescript snippet . both wants to achieve the same . however console.log prints different value. any idea what is wrong? why the code 2 prints false .

```
var regex1 = new RegExp(/^FEDEX /)
var messagePrefix = "FEDEX "
console.log(regex1.test(messagePrefix)); // this prints true 

let messageControlValue:string = "FEDEX "
let regex2:RegExp = new RegExp(/^messageControlValue/);
console.log(regex2.test(messagePrefix)); // this prints false
```

really appreciatiate any help
thanks

Comment: Because `messageControlValue` in `new RegExp(/^messageControlValue/)` is a `messageControlValue` string, not a `messageControlValue` variable. You meant to use `new RegExp("^" + messageControlValue)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in the second one you're literally testing for the string `messageControlValue`. Construct it like so:

```
let regex2: RegExp = new RegExp(`^${messageControlValue}`);
```

Or:

```
let regex2: RegExp = new RegExp("^" + messageControlValue);
```

Comment: excellant thank you

Comment: No problem @knowledgeseeker, always glad to help.

Comment: could you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57290784/why-i-am-not-able-to-make-the-text-area-partially-non-editable-in-angular-5-and